# Locate the saved template of minknow

Tags: ngs, sequence-analysis, linux, genome-sequencing, minknow

I am using minknow on ubuntu. After saving the template (settings), where is that file locally stored in the system?
Also what is its format/extension?

Comment: It would help to understand a little better what you are actually doing. I can find [a github page for MinKNOW](https://github.com/nanoporetech/minknow_api) and [a page with a ton of tutorials](https://nanoporetech.com/nanopore-sequencing-data-analysis). Where have you looked to try to find this information? Have you consulted the reference manual?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding. I want to share those files across a few systems, automate and load the exact same settings.  
There is no content regarding the local storage for the templates.